# Ban social networking. *twitch*

Tags: support, tags

Ban the tags [social-network](/questions/tagged/social-network) and [social-networking](/questions/tagged/social-networking) and block submission of all posts containing the sequence of characters "social network".

Please.

Make the hurting stop.

*twitch*

<sub>*twitch*</sub>

<sub>...</sub>

Comment: HOW WILL I BUILD MY FACEBOOK KILLER NOW

Comment: plz send me teh faecbook

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I love that mis-spelling of Facebook, it's so much closer to an accurate description of the site...

Comment: @DavidThomas [And this, ladies and gentleman, is why I don't use Facebook](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=559167#559167)

Comment: +1  seriously! I think the highest number of questions now come from android+facebook questions.

Answer (score 14):

Ignore these tags. They account for 895 questions out of over 3.5 million.