# Closed by status-declined?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, closed-questions

Here's an interesting thing I noticed on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84831/ban-social-networking-twitch) question:

[image]

So, how does [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) vote to close a question?

Comment: Looks like there used to be a user named "status-declined".

Comment: @Mysticial: What a coincidence.

Comment: Hmmm, it's pretty rare that a 3,000+ rep account would get deleted. Being on Meta, you have to be moderately well-known to reach 3,000. Does anyone know who it might have been?

Comment: @animuson given that you already know the user's name, I don't know how you want that question to be answered. I do remember a user named status-declined being active at one point, not too long ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Mysticial suggests, there was indeed once a user who went by the name status-declined. He had another name too, which you might recognize if you saw it.

But he decided to leave Meta, and took his name with him. All that remains are the echos...

Comment: "which you might recognize if you saw it..." Mysterious. I'm tempted to put a bounty on this question to encourage investigation, just out of sheer curiosity. But that would be wrong.